Unhandled Exception: HttpException: Connection closed before full header was received [FLUTTER]
I am working on a project where I am using a websocket. I am using it for a first time so I decided to first test it. I chose web_socket_channel: 2.4.0 package. I have added my code along with error below please go through it and suggest me a solution of the problem.
Error
D/EGL_emulation( 8164): app_time_stats: avg=20620.87ms min=20620.87ms max=20620.87ms count=1
E/flutter ( 8164): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: HttpException: Connection closed before full header was received, uri = http://192.168.5.104:8080/api/v1/language/get-all-active-languages
E/flutter ( 8164): 
E/flutter ( 8164): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: WebSocketChannelException: WebSocketChannelException: HttpException: Connection closed before full header was received, uri = http://192.168.5.104:8080/api/v1/language/get-all-active-languages
E/flutter ( 8164): #0      new IOWebSocketChannel._withoutSocket.<anonymous closure> (package:web_socket_channel/io.dart:119:24)
E/flutter ( 8164): #1      Stream.handleError.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/stream.dart:923:16)
E/flutter ( 8164): #2      _HandleErrorStream._handleError (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:269:17)
E/flutter ( 8164): #3      _ForwardingStreamSubscription._handleError (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:157:13)
E/flutter ( 8164): #4      _RootZone.runBinaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1606:10)
E/flutter ( 8164): #5      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendError.sendError (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:358:15)
E/flutter ( 8164): #6      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendError (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:376:7)
E/flutter ( 8164): #7      _BufferingStreamSubscription._addError (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:280:7)
E/flutter ( 8164): #8      _SyncStreamControllerDispatch._sendError (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:788:19)
E/flutter ( 8164): #9      _StreamController._addError (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:666:7)
E/flutter ( 8164): #10     _RootZone.runBinaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1606:10)
E/flutter ( 8164): #11     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendError.sendError (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:358:15)
E/flutter ( 8164): #12     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendError (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:376:7)
E/flutter ( 8164): #13     _BufferingStreamSubscription._addError (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:280:7)
E/flutter ( 8164): #14     _SyncStreamControllerDispatch._sendError (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:788:19)
E/flutter ( 8164): #15     _StreamController._addError (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:666:7)
E/flutter ( 8164): #16     new Stream.fromFuture.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/stream.dart:245:18)
E/flutter ( 8164): #17     _RootZone.runBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1666:54)
E/flutter ( 8164): #18     _FutureListener.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:171:22)
E/flutter ( 8164): #19     Future._propagateToListeners.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:852:47)
E/flutter ( 8164): #20     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:873:13)
E/flutter ( 8164): #21     Future._completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:649:5)
E/flutter ( 8164): #22     Future._asyncCompleteError.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:739:7)
E/flutter ( 8164): #23     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:40:21)
E/flutter ( 8164): #24     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:49:5)

Code:
 final channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect(
    Uri.parse(
        'ws://192.168.5.104:8080/api/v1/language/get-all-active-languages'),
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  );

  streamListener() {
    channel.stream.listen((message) {
      print(message);
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    streamListener();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: channel.stream,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return Text(snapshot.hasData ? '${snapshot.data}' : 'sdadsa');
        },
      ),
    );
  }

Actual API and it's output: It is a chat api which has to be executed continuously so that screen updates with a new message send by sender.
{{localUrl}}/chat/get-chat-history/66031ebc40dbc657b9f815e5
{
    "success": true,
    "statusCode": 200,
    "message": "Operation Successful",
    "statusMessage": "Success",
    "data": {
        "chatHistory": [
            {
                "_id": "6653535805176abed962fc2f",
                "sender": {
                    "profileImage": {
                        "url": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dc1duf3lc/image/upload/v1714981559/profiles/hhx8wjwo6pcumey8vikj.jpg",
                        "public_id": "profiles/hhx8wjwo6pcumey8vikj",
                        "isUploaded": true
                    },
                    "_id": "66388ab79b98ca0c2c1c5ca3",
                    "firstName": "test",
                    "lastName": "test"
                },
                "receiver": {
                    "profileImage": {
                        "url": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dc1duf3lc/image/upload/v1711480357/profiles/g8sgdg7fk5gvy7urvwui.jpg",
                        "public_id": "profiles/g8sgdg7fk5gvy7urvwui",
                        "isUploaded": true
                    },
                    "_id": "66031ebc40dbc657b9f815e5",
                    "firstName": "Test",
                    "lastName": "Test farmer"
                },
                "content": "test message",
                "createdAt": "2024-05-26T15:20:56.393Z",
                "updatedAt": "2024-05-26T15:20:56.393Z",
                "__v": 0
            },
            {
                "_id": "6653534005176abed962fc28",
                "sender": {
                    "profileImage": {
                        "url": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dc1duf3lc/image/upload/v1714981559/profiles/hhx8wjwo6pcumey8vikj.jpg",
                        "public_id": "profiles/hhx8wjwo6pcumey8vikj",
                        "isUploaded": true
                    },
                    "_id": "66388ab79b98ca0c2c1c5ca3",
                    "firstName": "test",
                    "lastName": "test"
                },
                "receiver": {
                    "profileImage": {
                        "url": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dc1duf3lc/image/upload/v1711480357/profiles/g8sgdg7fk5gvy7urvwui.jpg",
                        "public_id": "profiles/g8sgdg7fk5gvy7urvwui",
                        "isUploaded": true
                    },
                    "_id": "66031ebc40dbc657b9f815e5",
                    "firstName": "Test",
                    "lastName": "Test farmer"
                },
                "content": "test message",
                "createdAt": "2024-05-26T15:20:32.971Z",
                "updatedAt": "2024-05-26T15:20:32.971Z",
                "__v": 0
            }
        ]
    }
}


What happens if you just request http://192.168.5.104:8080/api/v1/language/get-all-active-languages using a browser, or postman, or Dart's http.get?

Yes, It's a GET API returns data.

What data does it return? And, does Dart's http.get fetch it ok? If this is just a GET endpoint, why would you try to connect using web sockets?

Richard, Actually it is a chat API which has to be run continuously so that screen updates with a new message sent by sender.

So the server doesn't actually implement a websocket interface at all, correct? Try polling the endpoint using a timer for now. See if you can get the server to switch to websockets for greater efficiency.

The backend developer has implemented the websocket at backend. How can I implement it in frontend code. Please guide.

Since you are using http at the moment, grab a packet capture of the connection. If it isn't obvious what's wrong from that, ask a new question.
